# Attach to 'screen' session with creating a new screen window

Tags: linux, shell, gnu-screen, detach

I have a screen session running with several windows.  I want to attach to it, create a new screen window within it and start a shell in that new window.

**Question:  How can I do this from the command line outside the screen session?**

I already tried a lot, e. g. `screen -x` (but it attaches to one of the existing screen windows; it does not create a new one nor does it start a new shell).  Any hints are welcome.

Environment is Linux (Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: Seems like there is no standard way of doing it. You can search in the [mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/screen-users/)

Comment: I would have accepted that as an answer because I found something there, thank you! :)

Comment: @Alfe if you found a proper answer, post it yourself. You are allowed to accept your own answer after a while if it is a proper answer. Besides i'm curious :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To choose a window to join, use the `-p` option. Giving `+` will create a new one, so your command is simply:

```
screen -x session_name -p +
```

This is documented on the man page:

> -p n̲u̲m̲b̲e̲r̲_o̲r̲_n̲a̲m̲e̲|̲-̲|̲=̲|̲+̲
>
> ```
> Preselect a window. This is useful when you want to reattach to a  
> specific windor or you want to send a command via the "-X" option  
> to a specific window. As with screen's select commant, "-" selects  
> the blank window. As a special case for reattach, "=" brings up the  
> windowlist on the blank window.
> ```

Comment: I looked at my manpage again (version 4.00.03jw4) and found only the `-p number_or_name` (not the `|-|=|+`).  Then I looked at a slightly newer version (4.01.00devel) and found your synopsis line.  Confusing is that the text you pasted comes from the older man page (describing nothing about the `+`) while the newer manpage in my tests had this additional text describing the `+`: `… while a "+" will create a new window.  The  command will not be executed if the specified window could not be found.`  So this is a new option!  Thanks for pointing this out, I think it solves my issue.

Answer (score 7):

Add new detached window to `sesion_name` and run `command`

```
screen -S sesion_name -x -X screen bash -c 'command; exec bash'
```

Answer (score 6):

I found something on the mailing list, thank you tuxuday :)

I'm doing it now this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -X screen -t NEWWINDOW  # create new window (switches existing attached terminal)
sleep 0.1
screen -X other  # switch existing attached terminal back to its old window
sleep 0.1
gnome-terminal -e 'screen -x -p NEWWINDOW'  # connect to new window
```

I'm not sure about those sleeps, maybe they aren't necessary in all environments, but I can wait those 0.2s easily.

My `.bash_aliases` is changing the screen window title with a delay, so the awkward `NEWWINDOW` won't stick for long (and thus not hinder further calls to this script).

Comment: The trick I got from the mailing list was the `screen -X other`.

Comment: take a look at this [blog entry](https://rohieb.wordpress.com/2010/07/30/gnu-screen-start-with-multiple-windows-and-commands/). It recommends using a session command file (just a file with all the commands like `screen`, `select` and `other`) and run `screen -X source sessionfile` instead of calling `screen -X` multiple times. Good approach

Comment: I'm calling `screen -X` just twice … but if that script grows, the session command file approach is worth having a look at for sure :)

Comment: Yes, you are right, i just pointed it because i found it neat.